# questions on ruby on rails drivers

Tags: ruby, neo4j, driver

I'm very novice when it comes to using neo4j, so I want to start asking a question on what kinda driver is prefered to use in a ruby on rails project. I looked at neo4js website and found the following drivers:

NeoID
Keymaker
neo4j.rb
neography

what is the prefered way for connecting to a neo4j database, and why is it a prefered way? Is it correct that there is a REST way and an embedded way?

Comment: Neo4j.rb in her latest Version 3 is really rocking ;-) BTW the guys are now heading to SFO for the Graphconnect conference so you'll may have to wait for having answers from the core developers during the next 2-3 days ;-)

Comment: Hi there! I'm heading to SFO on Monday and glued to my computer working on a Hackathon over the weekend, so I'm around to answer any questions about Neo4j.rb you may have while that's going on. As far as the "preferred way," it really depends on what you're looking for. If you want to use JRuby or tap into the Neo4j Java API directly, you need to go embedded, so choose a gem that supports that. If you want a REST wrapper, Neography is great. If you want full Rails integration, Neo4j.rb is the way to go.

Comment: I want to make a research paper on  "Pros/cons using Neo4j against relational database" and I start by investigating the possibilities of connecting to a community and/or enterprise neo4j server. I think it's hard to find technical information on how neo4jrb, neography and so on works.

-how does this driver work? information about its architecture and/or how it works under the covers.

-how does it work with activerecord? I'm having both a postgres and neo4j database connected.

-can I use the same driver for both postgres and neo4j, so I'm able to use different relational and graph databases

Comment: I forgot to mention I want to connect my ruby on rails project to grapheneDB

Comment: Hey James, I'm one of the founders of GrapheneDB. Neography is a thin wrapper around the REST interface and Neo4j.rb is an ActiveRecord-like adapter that provides syntactic sugar that hooks into your models. Both work with GrapheneDB.

Comment: Good to hear that I can use neography and neo4j.rb for GrapheneDB. I hope I can get a better understanding of how they work under the covers, because I have to argument my choice in a research paper

Comment: @JamesRamsfield most of those questions are extremely vague, just like we've been saying in the Neo4jrb Google Group. Are you comfortable with Ruby? The best way to find these answers is to spend time with the code, specs, and documentation. People can answer specific questions but we can't write your research paper for you. "How does this driver work" is not a good question for anybody unless you want an answer like, "It makes a REST query and creates an object with the response."

Comment: Sorry, I don't share your whole oppinion. My oppinion is the best start of using a gem is knowing some details on how it works. Then you try to use it and figure some out some more.  I think the documentation on neo4jrb is not specific enough. I don't even sure how to install it on ruby on rails. True I'm a novice and I haven't worked that much with ruby on rails. I was hoping finding just a half page long description on how it works. That's all. How can I connect to neo4j enterprise server.

Comment: No, you are not writing my research paper by writing some more lines in the documentation about how it is intended to work. Don't worry I can write my research paper by my self. It would be great that I shouldn't use a month just by figure out how to connect to neo4j and understand the main difference of NeoID Keymaker neo4j.rb and neography.

Comment: So nobody can benefit of understanding the choices you have for connecting to a neo4j database? They all have to spend a month or to just understand how these drives without some minor knowledge of how they are intended to be used?

Comment: and how they works in theory? Anyway, not a big deal I just figure it out my self as I would be doing anyway. It just would have been nice to find some documentation that says something like "Neo4jrb is ...blabla...and in works like..blabla ...when you are using it with....". That would have given me some better headstart on how they work.

Comment: Are you familiar with Ruby on Rails and ActiveRecord? Neo4jrb works in a very similar way to that: data is loaded from the server and wrapped in classes. Did you go through the first few pages of the wiki, starting at https://github.com/neo4jrb/neo4j/wiki/Neo4j.rb-v3-Introduction? Basic setup is covered in those pages. Add the gem, install the server -- use community, you do not need enterprise at this point. Most of what you know from Rails and ActiveRecord still applies but where there are differences, the docs spell it out.

Comment: Basic setup is https://github.com/neo4jrb/neo4j/wiki/Neo4j-v3-Setup, node models are https://github.com/neo4jrb/neo4j/wiki/Neo4j%3A%3AActiveNode, relationship models are https://github.com/neo4jrb/neo4j/wiki/Neo4j%3A%3AActiveRel, relationship syntax is https://github.com/neo4jrb/neo4j/wiki/Neo4j-v3-Declared-Relationships, and so on down the side of the page. If you have questions about anything that process, we can answer them.

Comment: Here's an intro screencast. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bDjbqRL9HcM

Comment: Here's a great introductory blog. http://www.jayway.com/2014/09/06/neo4j-rb-3-0-rc/

Comment: Yes, I am familiar with ruby on rails and activerecord. I have read Rails 4 in Action and The Well-Grounded Rubyist and some of the stuff on their webpage. Yes, I did go through neo4jrb wiki, I just miss a better introduction on what purpose this neo4jrb is intended to solve and how it does it in theory. I will look into your screencast intro, thx for that

Comment: The gem lets you use Neo4j with Rails instead of ActiveRecord. Rather than `class Student < ActiveRecord::Base`, you do `class Student; include Neo4j::ActiveNode`. It lets a Rails developer work with Neo4j using the same or very similar methods that they learned with plain old Rails.